# Use JSON Into An Object Model or Plain JSON

Tags: javascript, json, oop, javascript-objects

I'm doing a research about the subject of JSON Deserialization Into An Object Model, what do you think about it?

Would you prefer to use JSON from the server as is or converting it to Object Model (concrete JS objects)

What are the benefits of mapping it to Objects and not use the raw JSON, what are the negative aspects ?
What are the performance implications?

Our legacy developer wrote an SDK / DAL with a mapper function that traversing the JSON and make concrete objects,
you can see the implementation here : https://gist.github.com/send2moran/211a2eb19c4a7bf494e8

Would you work with the parsed JSON or prefer to use a mapping function?

Comment: if you need methods/inheritance, upgrade it. if you just need data, "JSON" is fine.

Comment: I don't see your point. JSON means _JavaScript Object Notation_, i.e. it already is an object...

Comment: This is the point .. i had a debate with the other developers in my team ..
i would like to see what other javascript developers thing about it ..

Comment: Raw JSON is a String. You can't do much with data inside a String.

Comment: @joews i mean JSON after parsing as an object

Comment: @dandavis actually my implementation is something like that:

https://gist.github.com/send2moran/18add3a4fbb67cfd755d